# vfolds_cv() suceeds in R script, fails in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working on an R assignment (using RStudio) that must be submitted as an Rmarkdown file. I completed the assignment in an R script with no issue.

As I converted the R script to an Rmarkdown file, I find I am unable to create folds in Rmarkdown.

running code from R script (console output):

```
> 
> set.seed(135)n 
> product_folds <- vfold_cv(product_train, strata = Product)
> product_folds

#  10-fold cross-validation using stratification 
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   splits               id    
   <list>               <chr> 
 1 <split [61405/6824]> Fold01
 2 <split [61405/6824]> Fold02
 3 <split [61405/6824]> Fold03
 4 <split [61406/6823]> Fold04
 5 <split [61406/6823]> Fold05
 6 <split [61406/6823]> Fold06
 7 <split [61406/6823]> Fold07
 8 <split [61407/6822]> Fold08
 9 <split [61407/6822]> Fold09
10 <split [61408/6821]> Fold10
>
```

running same code from Rmarkdown script (html output):

```
#  10-fold cross-validation using stratification 
splits
<list>
id
<chr>
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold01          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold02          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold03          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold04          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold05          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold06          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold07          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold08          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold09          
<S3: vfold_split>   Fold10          
1-10 of 10 rows
```

Observations:

- Rmarkdown code ran much slower
- Rmarkdown shows no split info, results in modeling failing
- I check the 'product_train' dataframes in both scripts, and the dataframes appear to be identical

Any clues?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: This is an excerpt from a 600 line script. I'll try ti create a reprex and post if here. Thanks for responding.